# pedometer application

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I try to calculate a miles per hours. For this I write a code like this

```
mint=sec/60;
hour=mint/60;
mph=miles/hour;
nsstring *speed=[nsstring stringwithformat:@"%5.2f",mph];

[mph settext: speed];
```

I get a miles from this code

```
miles = (steps *steplength)/1500;
NSString *distance =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%5.3f",TotalDistance];
[Miles1 setText:distance];
```

And the error is shown me like this

> miles per hour ans is (inf)

help me out

Comment: What's with all the pedometer questions lately?  This other user is asking an almost identical set of questions: http://stackoverflow.com/users/379760/harishdy007

Comment: @Brad Larson: there's obviously a huge shortage of pedometer apps on iPHone.  In fact, I'm thinking of writing one myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the minute count is < 60, then `hour` will be zero (if that's an integer division) and `mph` becomes `inf`.